# Sort Multidimensional Array with two columns

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a Multidimensional Array which has 2 columns (by using javascript)

```
  var arr = [];
    arr[0] = [1, 0];
    arr[1] = [1, 1];
    arr[2] = [1, 2];
    arr[3] = [1, 3];
    arr[4] = [1, 4];
    arr[5] = [2, 0];
    arr[6] = [2, 1];
    arr[7] = [2, 2];
    arr[8] = [2, 3];
    arr[9] = [3, 0];
    arr[10] = [3, 1];
    arr[11] = [3, 2];
    arr[12] = [3, 3];
```

how can i get results like below

```
[1, 0]
[2, 0]
[3, 0]
[1, 1]
[2, 1]
[3, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
[3, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[3, 3]
```

appreciate all the help

thanks

Comment: `arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] - b[1] || a[0] - b[0]; });`

Comment: awesome man, your the best ! :)